# Dynamically Generated Divs with Unique IDs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This code generates a div, each new one with a different id. After one press of the button, everything works. After the second press, the id of the first div created becomes the same as the new div created. How do I make it so that the past div ids are not changed?

```
var newdiv = 11;
var newimg = 7;
var lastimg = 0;
var divid = "";

$(document).ready(function(){

$("#divcreate").click(function(){
     divid = "div"+newdiv;
     $("#adddivs").append('<td><div id="div'+ newdiv +'" ondrop="drop(event, divid)" ondragover="allowDrop(event, divid)"><img id="drag'+ newimg +'" src="#" alt="your image" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" width="100" height="100"/></div></td>');
     $("#div"+newdiv).css({"width": "100px", "height": "100px", "margin": "10px",  "padding": "10px", "border": "1px dashed orange", "border-radius": "15px"});
     newdiv += 1;
     newimg += 1;
});
});
```

Comment: I've since managed to find the solution myself. Thanks to those who answered!

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to be working fine in this snippet.

```js
var newdiv = 11;
var newimg = 7;
var lastimg = 0;
var divid = "";

$(document).ready(function(){

$("#divcreate").click(function(){
     divid = "div"+newdiv;
     $("#adddivs").append('<td><div id="div'+ newdiv +'" ondrop="drop(event, divid)" ondragover="allowDrop(event, divid)"><img id="drag'+ newimg +'" src="#" alt="your image" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" width="100" height="100"/></div></td>');
     $("#div"+newdiv).css({"width": "100px", "height": "100px", "margin": "10px",  "padding": "10px", "border": "1px dashed orange", "border-radius": "15px"});
     newdiv += 1;
     newimg += 1;
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="adddivs"></div>
<button id="divcreate">click</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I checked this out and it worked fine :

```js
var newdiv = 11;
var newimg = 7;
var lastimg = 0;
var divid = "";

$(document).ready(function(){

$("#divcreate").click(function(){
     divid = "div"+newdiv;
     $("#adddivs").append('<td><div id="div'+ newdiv +'" ondrop="drop(event, divid)" ondragover="allowDrop(event, divid)"><img id="drag'+ newimg +'" src="#" alt="your image" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" width="100" height="100"/></div></td>');
     $("#div"+newdiv).css({"width": "100px", "height": "100px", "margin": "10px",  "padding": "10px", "border": "1px dashed orange", "border-radius": "15px"});
     newdiv += 1;
     newimg += 1;
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="divcreate">Click !</div>
<div id="adddivs"></div>
```

But if you have problem with this code, you can define the variables into `$(document).ready(function(){` , So the code should be look like this :

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
var newdiv = 11;
var newimg = 7;
var lastimg = 0;
var divid = "";

$("#divcreate").click(function(){
     divid = "div"+newdiv;
     $("#adddivs").append('<td><div id="div'+ newdiv +'" ondrop="drop(event, divid)" ondragover="allowDrop(event, divid)"><img id="drag'+ newimg +'" src="#" alt="your image" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" width="100" height="100"/></div></td>');
     $("#div"+newdiv).css({"width": "100px", "height": "100px", "margin": "10px",  "padding": "10px", "border": "1px dashed orange", "border-radius": "15px"});
     newdiv += 1;
     newimg += 1;
});
});
```